# GUI gets blank while processing

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface

I have an application which runs a function in background, Here is my main class

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h" // for CPLMalloc()
#include "ogr_srs_api.h"
#include <QDir>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QThread>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>

#include "databasemanager.h"
#include <sqlite_connection.h>
#include "locationinfo.cpp"
#include "gdal_wrap.h"
#include "gdalwarper.h"
#include "gdal_dem.h"
#include "shapefile_importer.h"
#include "gdal_contour.h"

using namespace QtConcurrent;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{


    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->startProcess, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (StartProcess()));

}




void MainWindow::StartProcess(){


    sendinfo("Starting Process... Note that the input images <b>must<\b> be in ESPG:3857.");

    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
                                                    "/home",
                                                    QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                    | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);


    if(dir==""){
        sendwarning("nothing is selected.");
            return;
    }
    sendinfo("The selected folder is: "+dir);
    QFuture<void> f1 = run(std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&MainWindow::RunProcess), this),dir);
    f1.waitForFinished();


}





void MainWindow::RunProcess(QString dir){

......

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

As you can see I am running my function in a QtConcurrent function, so based on my googles there must not any blank GUI but when I run application it makes GUI blank in linux and if I do not click some place on GUI it will close my application.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're running it synchronously because you call `waitForFinished()`. What did you expect to happen, except that it would wait until the `Future` finished? Then Qt's main loop never gets a chance to update the GUI.

Comment: Use the QFutureWatcher signal to wait for the end of the execution.

Comment: @underscore_d so I have to remove that line?

Comment: @eyllanesc Hi, well can I also listen to cancel button too? I mean sending signals into my function?

Comment: to what function?

Comment: If you are not going to do an action after finishing running run, you do not need f1.waitForFinished () ;, if you want to execute it something at the end it uses the finished signal of QFutureWatcher

Comment: @to my runprocess function. I must find some examples how to use Qfuturewatcher. thanks